# Visual flow on lightning - need to open in new window

Tags: visualforce, lightning, visual-workflow

I have a visual flow (flow) that is embeded in Visualforce(VF) page. 
We are planning to move to lightning, migration development work in progress.

I have detail page button on Contact page that triggers the visual flow.  It is working fine, but flow screen appears on contact record page itself like screen appear on this link - http://www.screencast.com/t/dDm3Tbxp1R (please click).

I want VF embeded flow screen to appear in new window (like popup window similar publisher action page) on lighning contact record page, so that user can continue to see the contact page

Any guidance in doing that ?

**Visualforce page with Visual FLOW code is as below :**

Visual Flow name is create_opportunity

.FlowContainer{
    width:50%;
    }

Comment: Create a new VF page that has only the visual flow on it. Then change your detail button to open that VF page in a new window instead of firing the visual workflow.

Comment: @caleb.breckon, please look into my code update. Currently VF page does have visual flow, VF page is being called from detail page button. It is not appearing in new window.  Any changes required in VF page to meet the lightning platform?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have Lightning enabled in any of my orgs so I cannot verify how that works. You configured the detail button using Customize > Contacts > Buttons, Links, and Actions, with display type "Detail Page Button", Behavior as "Display in new window" and Content Source as your VF page containing the visual flow?